# Import the code inside my class Component into a different Angular TS file

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to import the code inside my class Component into a different Angular ts file? Because I'm working on a HTML structure that is going to repeat in different parts of the project, but that HTML structure only works with the code I have inside the class component. It's not going to be a reusable component, just HTML structure. So, I was thinking how to import the code that I have inside my class Component.

```
export class Component{
    constructor() { }

    @ViewChild('Button') Button!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
    @ViewChild('level2') level2!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
    @ViewChild('IconButton') IconButton!: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

    //  Hide list result when clicking anywhere on the screen
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        const targetElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
        const ButtonTest = this.Button.nativeElement;
        const level2Element = this.level2.nativeElement;
        const IconButton = this.IconButton.nativeElement;

        if (targetElement === IconButton) {
            level2Element.classList.toggle('show-list');
            console.log('CLICK');
        } else {
            level2Element.classList.remove('show-list');
        }
    }


    // Avoid page refresh on Storybook
    ClickHandler(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to, you can use the same HTML file as the template for different components by simply specifying the same file as the `template` in the `@Component` decorator. Otherwise, I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Yes you can have a create a custom directive with all the code that your component is holding. Use that directive in templates of multiple components